# How to avoid full table scan in subview of mysql view

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-view

This issue is on MySQL:

I need to self join the table to get the last record in each group and join that record with another table.

Assume,
`comments` table has 4 columns `pkid`, `session_id`, `comment`, `create_date` (`pkid` is the primary key and there will be a number of comments for each `session_id`)

`comment_channel` table have `session_id`, `channel` (there will be just one row for each `session_id`)

now I need to get the last `comment` in each `session_id` and its `channel`

So I can write a query something like this:

```
SELECT t1.session_id, t1.comment, t3.channel, t1.create_date
FROM comments t1
    join (
        SELECT max(pkid)
        FROM comments
        GROUP BY session_id
    ) t2 on t1.pkid = t2.pkid
    left join comment_channel t3 on t1.session_id = t3.session_id
```

If I want to write this as a view then I can't put the same query because MySQL doesn't support subqueries in VIEW.

so i have to write two views:

View 1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW comment_channel_view AS 
SELECT t1.session_id, t1.comment, t3.channel, t1.create_date FROM comments t1
    join comment_max_id_view t2 on t1.pkid = t2.pkid
    left join comment_channel t3 on t1.session_id = t3.session_id
```

View 2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW comment_max_id_view AS 
SELECT max(pkid)
FROM comments
GROUP BY session_id
```

here the problem is, if I use this view to select for a particular period

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM comment_channel_view
WHERE create_date between '2019-04-05' and '2019-04-10'
```

then the `comment_max_id_view` is doing a full table scan instead of just the selected date range, which takes more than 5 minutes to get the result. If I put the date range condition within the subquery then I am getting the result just in milliseconds.

so what should I do in view to avoid full table scan in `comment_max_id_view`?